# Can I turn on extended regular expressions support in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, command-line

The characters for extended regular expressions are invaluable; is there a way to turn them on so that I don't have to escape them in my Vim regex, much like the `-E` flag I can pass to grep(1)?

Comment: "Extended regular expressions" is kind of a terrible term for it, given that having to backslash all control characters isn't really core to the concept of regular expressions, but rather of an aberration (an unfortunate situation which UNIX terminals seem to have created?)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Do `:help magic` in vim and you'll see there are four levels (very magic, magic, nomagic, and very nomagic) but only the two central ones can be set globally (the default is magic, and with `:set` commands you can only toggle between magic and nomagic); start your RE with `\v` to make all the rest of it "very magic" ("all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning") -- but that applies only to that one specific RE!-)

Comment: @Cimbali, the Wayback Machine has a copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20100725091217/http://briancarper.net/blog/448/vim-regexes-are-awesome

Comment: I am not familiar with the `grep -E` syntax and couldn't find anything about whitespace in the `:help magic`. Does this answer mean, that extended mode is possible with one of the magic levels or does it say that it is not possible? (How could I go about making my regexes more readable, for example in a syntax file?)

Comment: If using `\v` with search-and-replace, make sure to put it **after** the delimiter: `:%s~\v^(foo)$~\1bar~gc`

Answer (score 15):

A workaround is to remap / to prefix searches with "very magic" automatically:

```
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
```

Comment: @eduncan911, will this also enable `very magic` behavior in `substitute` and `global` commands in vim?

Comment: Not directly no, just remaps search.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this without changing the global `magic` option in vim, which causes all kinds of mayhem in plugins that use regexes. It hadn't occurred to me to just remap the `/` command. Thank you; this is brilliant.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! You can also find required matches with `/` at first and then use `:s//new value/` for their substitution. It works with another commands expecting search pattern as well (e.g. `:g//p`)