# How to make Vim not require backslashes before regex control characters

Tags: regex, vim, quoting

The number of slashes one must use in Vim regexes is very, very unfortunate:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\)\(.*\s\+\)\(\w\+\)$/\3\2\1/
```

Is there any way to reverse the rules so that I can write

```
:%s/(\w+)(.*\s+)(\w+)$/\3\2\1/
```

And I would only have to quote `(`, `)`, `.`, `*`, `+`, etc. if I want them to match that literal character?

Comment: ["Preceding your pattern with `\v` will make the pattern “magic”"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23434/279389). See [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic).

Comment: Also, see [How to enable “Very magic” mode in vim with vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273133) and [Can I turn on extended regular expressions support in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623160) SO posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you refer to is called "very magic" mode (see `:help magic`).

You can switch it on for an expression with the `\v` flag:

```
:%s/\v(\w+)(.*\s+)(\w+)$/\3\2\1/
```

By default this is not enabled and it's not a good idea at all to enable it by default. But you can always use it in a per-expression manner.

There are two different magic modes, switched on by `\v` and `\m`, and switched off by `\V`, `\M` respectively. Just like case-sensitivity via `\c` and `\C`, you can use those flags to make only a part of the expression magic.

But if you switch it on at the start of the expression and don't switch it off again, the entire expression is seen as magic.