# Recognise #define compiler directive in fortran with ctags

Tags: vim, fortran, ctags, compiler-directives

I would like to configure ctags to recognize compiler directives in a fortran code. More specifically, I would like to match the following vim search result

```
/\v[ \t]*#define[ \t]+([-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?]+)/
```

where \v induces the very magic level (see [Can I turn on extended regular expressions support in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623160/can-i-turn-on-extended-regular-expressions-support-in-vim)). Alternatively, the search using a normal regular expression

```
/[ \t]*#define[ \t][ \t]*\([-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?][-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?]*\)/
```

could be used. If general compiler directives are found, that would help me too. A practical application would be that when pressing <C+]>, when having my cursor at _ABORT in the following piece of code

```
_ABORT("delta_time is too small")
```

I would be redirected to the corresponding definition

```
#define _ABORT(msg) call abimem_abort(msg, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Based on https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/, I tried to add either

```
--regex-fortran=/[ \t]*#define[ \t]+([-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?]+)/\1/d,directives/
```

or

```
--regex-fortran=/[ \t]*#define[ \t][ \t]*\([-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?][-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?]*\)/\1/d,directives/
```

to ~/.ctags. Based on http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html, I also tried to add --line-directives=yes, but in neither case I could succeed in the practical application I gave as an example above. I can already see the additional kind when using

```
ctags --list-kinds
```

but that's all. What went wrong?

Comment: Your first try works with the sample provided.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it works now. My current ~/.ctags is

```
--fortran-kinds=+i
--recurse=yes
--exclude=.git
--regex-fortran=/[ \t]*#define[ \t]+([-[:alnum:]*+!_:\/.?]+)/\1/d,directives/
```

Probably this has to do with the fact that I previously had put a '\v' in the ~/.ctags (and did not copied this properly to the question). Could someone explain why this '\v' must not be present there, though vim is configured to need it for extended regex's?

Another thing that happened between previous try and now is a reboot (clean-up of temporary space etc.), which might help if still stuck.

Moreover, one should remark that the extra regex is not always necessary. Following macro definition was found without the regex:

```
#  define MSG_ERROR(msg)   call libpaw_msg_hndl(msg,"ERROR"  ,"PERS")
```